# I/O with Erlang, trying to get input file into list

Tags: erlang

```
-module(test).
-export([run/1]).

open_file(FileName, Mode) ->
    {ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [Mode, binary]),    Device.

close_file(Device) ->
    ok = file:close(Device).

read(File) ->
    case file:read_line(File) of
        {ok, Data} -> [Data | read(File)];
        eof        -> []
    end.
run(InputFileName) ->
    Device = open_file(InputFileName, read),
    Data = read(Device),
    [First |TheRest] = Data,
    io:format("First line is ~p ~n", [First]),
    close_file(Device).
```

The original file

```
d1  and is  program program the
d2  a   apply   copyleft    free    free    freedom
d3  copyleft    copyleft    share   share   users
d4  released    software    works
d5  licenses    licenses    licenses    licenses    licenses    software
d8  apply
```

somehow turns into

```
50> test:run("input.txt").
First line is <<"d1\tand\tis\tprogram\tprogram\tthe\n">> 
ok
```

Is this a special way of representing a list? or do I need to use kind of module to convert the read into a list?

My ultimate goal is to make a key pair with a list:

```
{d1 [and is program program the]}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're reading from your file is represented as a binary, rather than a string, because you're specifying `binary` mode when you open the file:

```
{ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [Mode, binary]), Device.
```

If you change this to:

```
{ok, Device} = file:open(FileName, [Mode]), Device.
```

your result becomes:

> First line is "d1  and is  program program the\n"

To get the ultimate result, change your `read/1` function to this:

```
read(File) ->
    case file:read_line(File) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            [First|Rest] = string:tokens(Data, " \t\n"),
            [{First,string:join(Rest, "\t")} | read(File)];
        eof -> []
    end.
```

With this change, your program prints:

> First line is {"d1","and\tis\tprogram\tprogram\tthe"}

where the second element is a string in which the tokens are tab-separated as in your original data. If you want the first element, `"d1"`, to instead be an atom `d1` (I can't tell for sure from your question if this is what you want), you can convert it with `list_to_atom/1`.

Comment: Hey! I just happened to glance at the back of my "Erlang Programming" book.